# JSF Datatable Cell - Cut text and replace with "..." if content too long

Tags: java, css, jsf, datatable, cell

I would like to cut off a text if it is too long for the cell and add three  dots "..." at the end (no wrapping). The problem is, that I cant just cut the content in java after XX symbols because 'i' takes less space than 'W', which in turn would look silly.

How can I achiev this (if possible without Java Script) with CSS/java?
Or is that not possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try CSS: Set a `max-width` and specify `text-overflow` with:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: You're welcome! I recently found this in someone else's code - after years of writing extra getter methods for proper formatting...